# Fail to install php-mbstring on CentOS 6.9 using yum

Tags: centos6, yum

I'm trying to install php-mbstring package using yum command -

```
yum install php-mbstring
```

But it fails, here is the output -

```
sudo yum install php-mbstring
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Existing lock /var/run/yum.pid: another copy is running as pid 15130.
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory :  38 M RSS (319 MB VSZ)
    Started: Sat Jun 24 17:25:17 2017 - 00:00 ago
    State  : Running, pid: 15130
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirrors.tds.net
 * extras: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * updates: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.3.3-49.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-49.el6 for package: php-mbstring-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mbstring-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-49.el6
           Installed: php-common-5.4.16-1.x86_64 (@powerstack)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-1
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-49.el6
           Available: php55w-common-5.5.38-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.38-1.w6
           Available: php56w-common-5.6.30-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-1.w6
           Available: php70w-common-7.0.15-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.15-1.w6
           Available: php70w-common-7.0.16-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.16-1.w6
           Available: php70w-common-7.0.17-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.17-1.w6
           Available: php70w-common-7.0.18-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.18-1.w6
           Available: php70w-common-7.0.19-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.19-1.w6
           Available: php70w-common-7.0.20-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.20-1.w6
           Available: php71w-common-7.1.1-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.1-1.w6
           Available: php71w-common-7.1.2-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.2-1.w6
           Available: php71w-common-7.1.3-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.3-1.w6
           Available: php71w-common-7.1.4-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.4-1.w6
           Available: php71w-common-7.1.5-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.5-1.w6
           Available: php71w-common-7.1.6-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.6-1.w6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Can anybody help me on this? Appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: You have a wild mix of different PHP versions/repositories in your system. Clean that stuff up so you have only one active version and then install the version of mbstring that is appropriate for your selected PHP version.

Comment: I'm afraid to do it as its a production server and I'm not a sysadmin :(

Answer (score -2):

you need to add your php version before package like : 
`yum install php71w-mbstring`
or `yum install php56w-mbstring`